# can anyone suggest me some tiny lightbox or modal dialogue box or thickbox to open a html or php page?

Tags: php, html

I have to open a page in a lightbox or thicbox style with a overlay image . I found thickbox on net but that is too big arnf 55 kb. I need a simpler and tiny js thing to do this. Can anyone plz suggest some??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent [Lightbox matrix](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) in which you can sort (and filter) by feature, size, framework and more. [Greybox](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/) seems to be the lightest one that meets your requirements.

Comment: The matrix link is awesome but it seems a little out of date. The library sizes have changed a bit in the last 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Colorbox: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: This assumes you're already using jQuery. While Colorbox itself is just 19kB, with jQuery it's 113kB.

Comment: Actually even with jQuery it's only 33kB. 9kB + 24kB

Answer (score 1):

Smallest thing that I use: SubModal

http://code.google.com/p/submodal/

Comment: +1 for being the only answer with a total size actually less than 55kB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Facebox](http://github.com/defunkt/facebox) and [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) both smaller than thickbox.

Comment: Both these require jQuery, adding 94kB to the size unless you're already using it for other purposes.

Comment: OP didn't specified he using jQuery or not. What more he using Thickbox with jQuery.

Comment: It's still an assumption, and thus it's worth mentioning that you've made this assumption.

Comment: Don't forget to add +1 because both smaller than 55kb ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) has the advantage that you can easily (through a webinterface) create a custom version of it containing only what you need.  That way it is very very lightweight.

If you download it for showing ONLY other web-pages without any connectors for other frameworks, the script itself is only 21k.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modal the comes inside the [KB JavaScript Framework](https://github.com/Xeoncross/kb_javascript_framework). It's only about 2KB in size - way smaller than anything here.